# Using differentials and given $h=f\circ\vec g$ find $h(1.02,1.99)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

**Using differentials find approximately $h(1.02,1.99)$ using that**

$$h=f\circ\vec g,\quad f(u,v)=3u+v^2,\quad\vec g(1,2)=(3,6),\quad D_{\vec g}(1,2)=\left(\begin{matrix}2&1\\3&5\end{matrix}\right).$$

---

What does it mean by "Using differentials"?

Anyway let $h(x,y)$ a differentiable function, because both $f$ and $\vec g$ are differentiable because the first one is a composition of sums and cuadratic, and the second because that has given us the jacobian, therefore their composition is also differentiable $\color{red}{(\text{in only one point or in the domain of }h)}$?
So we must find $$h(x,y)=h(x_0,y_0)+h'_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+h'_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0).$$

Using the composition of functions I get

$$\begin{cases}h'_x&=f'_u\cdot g'_x+f'_v\cdot g'_x\\h'_y&=f'_u\cdot g'_y+f'_v\cdot g'_y,\end{cases}$$ but I am not able to continue because I don't know how to evaluate the derivatives of $\vec h$ (for $f$ yes, finding its gradient). Also I do not know what is the value of $h(x_0,y_0)$.

Can anyone help me, please?

Thank you!

Comment: You provide $\quad D_{\vec g}$. But in which $(x,y)$ value is it?

Comment: *Using differentials* means: using the approximation $f(x+\delta)=f(x)+\delta f'(x)$

Comment: @N74 thank you. Hmmm... and in the case for $2$ variables? Something like $h(x+\delta_1,y+\delta_2)$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net yes, sorry, in $(1,2)$. Please see again the question.

Comment: You have already the right expression for $h$

Comment: @N74 thanks! So then we must evaluate $h$ in $(x,y)=(1.02,1.99)$... but first we need to find another components which I don't know how ;).

Comment: So use $\vec g(\vec p_0 + \vec \delta_p)=\vec g(\vec p_0)+ D_{\vec g} \vec \delta_p$

Comment: @N74 which property is that?

Comment: The vector form of my first comment... the derivative is replaced by the gradient in vector spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that 
$$D_{\vec g}(1,2)=\left(\begin{matrix}2&1\\3&5\end{matrix}\right)$$
you also have $D_f(3,6)= (3,12)$.

Now you can write $(1.02,1.99)=(1+0.02,2.0-0.01)=(1,2)+(0.02,-0.01)=(1,2)+(h,k)$.

Based on that, you can use the chain rule (which you used in your question using coordinates), namely

$$D_h(1,2)=D_f(3,6) \circ D_{\vec g}(1,2)$$

To get

$$h(1.02,1.99)\approx h(1,2)+D_h(1,2).(h,k)=45+(3,12)\left[\begin{pmatrix}2 &1\\
3&5\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0.02\\
-0.01\end{pmatrix}\right]=45.21$$

Comment: Thanks! What about the condition of differentiability? $h$ is differentiability near $(1,2)$ because both $f$ and $\vec g$ are differentiability? I mean, why can we apply the chain rule?

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and $g$ at $b=f(a)$ then $h =g \circ f$ is differentiable at $a$ and its derivative is given by the chain rule. This is the [chain rule theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).